# SyntaxError: invalid syntax — if statement inside if statement in a singe line

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

I can do smth like:

```
if maxoksum > 0: R = maxoksum
```

But if I try very similar thing like:

```
if oksum % 3 == 0: if oksum > maxoksum: maxoksum = oksum
```

I get SyntaxError:

```
    if oksum % 3 == 0: if oksum > maxoksum: maxoksum = oksum
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to get working if inside if in one line?

Comment: Why does it have to be a single line? Why can’t you combine the two conditions with `and`?

Comment: There is no way to put it all on a line. The single-line `if` is for a single statement. But you want a nested `if`.  That requires a block. And you can't put a block on a single line. If you must do it one one line (why?) then use `and`: if oksum % 3 == 0 and oksum > maxoksum: maxoksum = oksum

Comment: What you are doing wrong is expecting it to work. It doesn't work and that's all there is to it. You cannot do it on a single line.

Comment: Arguably an `if..: if..: ..` *could* work, but `if..: foo if..: bar` or `if..: if..: .. else:` are already syntactically impossible to disambiguate, so it’s simply not possible to write any such compound block statement.

Comment: @deceze, thanks for good explanation, now I understand it completely. I didn't want to use `if condition1 and condition2: ..` because I didn't want condition2 to be checked when condition1 = false. This becomes really reasonable when condition1 is simple and condition2 is smth like is_prime(very big number).

Comment: `and` is already *short circuiting* and won’t check condition 2 if condition 1 is false!

Comment: @deceze, didn't know it, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question because I can't mark comment as solution. Quoting the comment by @deceze:

> Arguably an `if..: if..: ..` could work, but `if..: foo if..: bar` or `if..: if..: .. else:` are already syntactically impossible to disambiguate, so it’s simply not possible to write any such compound block statement.